# Assigning OG group title to OG group image title field

Tags: 7, rules, organic-groups

Every member of my site can create groups (OG.) Each group requires a title, an image, and a mission statement. The image Title field is enabled because in some parts of the site, the group images are displayed as thumbnails without the group titles.

However, most users don't bother to fill in the image title field so there is no indication of the group's title or purpose.

The idea here is to have the title of the group show automatically when the mouse cursor hovers above the group image after the group is created.

Any idea on how to accomplish this feast?

Comment: Do you already have rules installed? Pretty sure that could be an easy solution.

Comment: Yes, I have Rules installed. but I can't find the appropriate data selectors after the event "After a group is created."

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event should be after saving new content of type: your group content type.
Then add a condition, entity has field: node > your image field.
You should then be able add a condition to check if that field is empty.

Your action would then be to set a data value on the image using the node title.

Comment: That was tricky, but it works well! Thanks. :)